# Application process: dealing with disappearing company

Tags: applications

1. You apply for a job at a huge company
2. Then after just a few days you get an email "I'm interested! Let's have a call! When are you available?"
3. You reply within 6 h
4. You get no reply for 5 days

What is the right thing to do here? I'm quite sure one reminder can be sent: an email or call. And then? Does it mean the company is not interested if no answer is given?

Comment: It might mean the person doing the interviewing went on vacation

Comment: @HLGEM Probably not. A responsible person who was genuinely interested in recruiting qualified candidates would've passed the baton.

Comment: Or he could have gone on emergency leave, sometimes the baton does not get passed and big companies work slowly in many cases anyway.

Comment: A huge companz have dissapeared? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If this is huge company there should be signature with complete contact profile on your email response

I think 5 days is sufficient time frame for follow up contact